# Flutter store list in Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store my uploaded images urls to Firestore as list.

Also I'm trying store multiple images for profile. This is how I am storing images. If there is any better way to do that please let me know.

```
await _firebaseFirestore.collection("noktalar").doc().set({

      'aciklama': aciklama,
      'lat': 123,
      'long': 123,
      'mailAdresi': mailAdresi,
      'noktaAdi': noktaAdi,
      'telefon': tel,
      'webAdresi': webAdresi,
      'yetkiliAdiSoyadi': yetkili,
      'resimler': FieldValue.arrayUnion(resimler)
    });
```

and I tried this also

```
     'resimler': imagesUrls.map((value) => value.toJson()).toList(),
```

Comment: Did my answer help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can basically store image URLs as a Strings and when you'll get them in code, you can just use split method to make list from String. That's pretty easy method to solve this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps:

1. First upload your image to Firebase Storage and get the download
   URL.
2. Now you have the download URL and you can Upload your Enter
   object to Cloud FireStore with the url.

You can use the below function to get the download url of uploaded image and then store them in a location in Firestore.

```
Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile ) async { 
    StorageReference ref = storage.ref().child("/photo.jpg");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile); 
    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = dowurl.toString(); 
    return url;
 }
```

You may also refer to the [blog](https://sanjeepan23.medium.com/adding-images-to-firebase-storage-and-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-6f0a09de4a5e).

Comment: of course i'm uploading my images to storage and get download url and put links in to list but i cant store my list into firebase array

Comment: Firebase does not support arrays directly, but it creates a list of objects with integers as key names. However, you can use the push() method to append data to a list in multiuser applications. You may refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) for more on this.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, there is no obligation to do this.